# Varnish accessing log files

Tags: varnish

I have a question. I am trying to access varnish logs (website is localhost) but when I type in varnishncsa -w test.log on the terminal it is just blank. Any ideas on how I can fix this? I check the /var/log.varnish/access.log and it is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `varnishncsa -w /var/log.varnish/access.log`, if that's the path where you want them, and make sure you current user has write access to that file.